# TableLayoutPanel new row columns not following set size

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel with 5 columns.

The widths of the columns have been set to fixed values to match their contents.

I have an add row button with the following code:

```
    private void addrowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RowStyle temp = configTLP.RowStyles[configTLP.RowCount - 1];
        configTLP.RowCount++;
        configTLP.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(temp.SizeType, temp.Height));
        configTLP.Controls.Add(new TextBox(), 0, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
        configTLP.Controls.Add(new TextBox(), 1, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
        configTLP.Controls.Add(new ComboBox(), 2, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
        configTLP.Controls.Add(new TextBox(), 3, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
        configTLP.Controls.Add(new Button(), 4, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
    }
```

When clicked, only the first, third and fifth columns retain their size as per screenshot below.

[image]

TableLayoutPanel settings:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to add `configTLP.SuspendLayout(); configTLP.Controls.Add(...) [...] configTLP.ResumeLayout(true);` and to dock your new Controls (e.g., `configTLP.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill}, 0, configTLP.RowCount - 1);`).

Comment: BTW, it looks like you could use a DataGridView instead of a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: @Jimi are you sure that TableLayoutPanel honors SuspendLayout? It doesn't override OnLayoutSuspended and I can't see any effect on the UI.

Comment: @Steeeve SuspendLayout is not actually relevant here. It's there (as usual) to follow the standard implementation. What is relevant in a ScrollableControl that is also an IExtenderProvider, is to call `PerformLayout()` (in a way or another). You may not *feel* it's necessary in all situations, but this Control participates in the layout, so you usually try to generate a default behavior. This is also applied in the Designer.

Comment: @Steeeve With *standard implementation* and *try to generate a default behavior* refer to the internal counter that couples `SuspendLayout()` and `PerformLayout()` calls (`ResumenLayout(true)` also calls `PerformLayout()`), so you don't go *out of synch* (there's sort of a check that should handle this, but...). It doesn't matter if the default LayoutEngine is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `{ Dock = DockStyle.Fill}` resolved the issue.

```
private void addrowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RowStyle temp = configTLP.RowStyles[configTLP.RowCount - 1];
    configTLP.RowCount++;
    configTLP.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(temp.SizeType, temp.Height));
    configTLP.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill}, 0, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
    configTLP.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill}, 1, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
    configTLP.Controls.Add(new ComboBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill}, 2, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
    configTLP.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill}, 3, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
    configTLP.Controls.Add(new Button() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill}, 4, configTLP.RowCount - 1);
}
```